# Return Second Value of the Column IF the first column empty in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this table in my Pandas Dataframe (Store_id and Sub_store)

```
           Store_id   Sub_store
1             26821           
2                       26821B
3             26823     26823AV
4                       26823B
5                      26824DCF
```

I would like to return the All_ID column by 1. Return the values of the stored_id column, IF empty return Sub_store column and strip de Strings Characters.

How I Can return the result "ALL ID" in my python Pandas Dataframe?

Expected Output:

```
ALL ID      Store_id   Sub_store
26821         26821           
26821                   26821B
26823         26823     26823AV
26823                   26823B
26824                   26824DCF
```

Comment: post ur expected output, and also highlight what steps u took so far in solving the problem

Comment: Empty means missing values or empty strings?

Comment: Means Missing Values. Looks ur first solution is good! Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution if empty values are missing values with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) for new column to first position:

```
#if need all integers form start of Sub_store strings
s = df['Store_id'].fillna(df['Sub_store'].str.extract('(\d+)'), expand=False)
#if need first 5 letters
#s = df['Store_id'].fillna(df['Sub_store'].str[:5])
df.insert(0, 'ALL ID', s)

print (df)
  ALL ID Store_id Sub_store
0  26821    26821       NaN
1  26821      NaN    26821B
2  26823    26823   26823AV
3  26823      NaN    26823B
4  26824      NaN  26824DCF
```

Solution if missing values are empty strings with [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
s = df['Store_id'].mask(df['Store_id'] == '', df['Sub_store'].str.extract('(\d+)',expand=False))
df.insert(0, 'ALL ID', s)

print (df)
  ALL ID Store_id Sub_store
0  26821    26821          
1  26821             26821B
2  26823    26823   26823AV
3  26823             26823B
4  26824           26824DCF
```

Comment: First solution is better because I can have an ID with 6-7 digits.

Comment: @SimonGIS - some problem here?

Comment: first solution : TypeError: "value" parameter must be a scalar, dict or Series, but you passed a "DataFrame"

Comment: second solution : NotImplementedError: cannot align with a higher dimensional NDFrame

Comment: @SimonGIS - Can you test if help parameter `expand=False`, [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61005218/revisions) answer